# How to calculate a reversed probability?

Tags: statistics

EDIT: I didn't know that the question was that trivial. I forgot it was high school math stuff. I asked it here because I just came across it on the internet. Sorry.

In a population, the probability of a boy being born is 0.52. In this population, 6% of girls and 5% of boys have sickle cell disease. What is the probability that a newborn with sickle cell disease is a boy?

Comment: This is a straight application of Bayes theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem, we can use Bayes' theorem:

*P(boy | sickle cell disease) = P(sickle cell disease | boy) * P(boy) / P(sickle cell disease)*

where P(boy | sickle cell disease) is the probability of a newborn with sickle cell disease being a boy, P(sickle cell disease | boy) is the probability of a boy having sickle cell disease (0.05), P(boy) is the probability of a newborn being a boy (0.52), and P(sickle cell disease) is the overall probability of a newborn having sickle cell disease.

To calculate P(sickle cell disease), we need to use the law of total probability:

*P(sickle cell disease) = P(sickle cell disease | girl) * P(girl) + P(sickle cell disease | boy) * P(boy)*

where P(sickle cell disease | girl) is the probability of a girl having sickle cell disease (0.06), P(girl) is the probability of a newborn being a girl (1 - 0.52 = 0.48), and P(sickle cell disease | boy) is the probability of a boy having sickle cell disease (0.05) as given in the problem.

Putting all the values into the equations, we get:

**P(sickle cell disease) = (0.06 * 0.48) + (0.05 * 0.52) = 0.0548**

**P(boy | sickle cell disease) = 0.05 * 0.52 / 0.0548 ≈ 0.04745**

Comment: The process is good but I think you made a mistake on the P(sickle cell disease) = (0.06 * 0.48) + (0.05 * 0.52), because it's equivalent to 0,0548 and not 0.0312

Comment: thanks, it's a mistake in the calculation  @RobertReynolds